# Installing Ubuntu by flash drive

Tags: flash, drive, usb-installation

If we are installing Ubuntu by flash drive can we generate the flashdrive with poweriso in another laptop?

Comment: I can't parse that question in a meaningful way. Could you please [edit] it to rephrase it to include exactly one predicate verb in each (sub-)clause? Also, what's a "poweriso"?

Answer (score -1):

Yes of course you can generate the flash drive using
Power iso.
If you are using windows os in that laptop then download the poweriso in windows 
Select image file(.iso) of ubuntu .
Select the disk you are using for booting.
Then burn it
..
If you are using ubuntu in another laptop then 
Use startup disk creator which is system application provided by ubuntu..
..
You can use 
1.universal usb installer
2.rufus
3.winusb

Softwares for making flash drive in windows

Hope it will help you